# docker-php-ext-install running every build making new images and leaving <none>

Tags: php, docker, mysqli

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.3.3-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
EXPOSE 80
```

Every time I run the following command docker will build a new image, download the mysqli package again and leaves a : images, when I am just simply changing a line in the php file.

```
docker build -t php-server .
```

Is there a way to make docker not re download the package and just update the image that already exists?

Comment: If `RUN` instruction is not related to `COPY` just swap lines. This is how docker image layering works. If a change in a line is detected then this and all following lines will be executed on a new  build.

Comment: Thank you @leopal, swapping the lines worked, it now says it uses cache when running the command